# Excluding Jars in Jboss-deployment-structure.xml from dependency ear

Tags: jar, dependencies, jboss7.x, ear, jboss6.x

this is my Jboss-Deployment-Structure.xml file:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">  
<ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>  
<deployment>
<exclude-subsystems>
<subsystem name="jaxrs" />
</exclude-subsystems>
<dependencies>  
<!-- add our own modules -->  
 <module name="org.jboss.remoting3" /> 
 <module name="deployment.ARXSecurityAPIToolkit.ear" export="true" />
 <module name="df.properties" />
</dependencies>
<exclusions>  
 <!-- Exclude org.jboss.remoting3, we added custom module  -->   
<module name="org.jboss.remoting3" /> 
</exclusions>
</deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Dependency deployment.ARXSecurityAPIToolkit.ear has several jars inside of it.
When creating a dependency, I want all jars in it except one(ARX.jar) to be a part of the dependency. How to exclude a particular jar(ARX.jar) from my ear in the dependency section.